# Составить правильно базу данных

Tags: база-данных

Нужно создать правильную базу данных.
Есть товары. Есть параметры товаров (не одинаковые). Есть ответы на параметры.

---

Например :

- Молоко
     {цена:1,качество:1,количество,4}
- Хлеб
     {цена:2,количество:3,продано:6}

---

Нужна таблица товаров, таблица параметров товаров, и куда то хранить ответы на параметры.

Как организовать это все, чтоб можно было добавлять (удалять) параметры, и легко работать с таблицой товаров.

Comment: А свои наброски-то есть? Вы задали очень абстрактный вопрос и хотите конкретный ответ.

Comment: @myvzar Гуглите EAV (Entity Attribute Value). другой вариант NoSQL. Третий вариант - денормализованная база по видам товаров (молоко в одной таблице, хлеб в другой) - бесперспективняк, упретесь в конце концов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаете таблицу товаров goods (id, name), таблицу параметров properties (id, name) и "корзину" для связи между ними goods_properties (id, id_good, id_property, property_value). Тогда запрос

```
select p.name, gp.property_value 
from goods_properties gp
inner join goods g on gp.id_good = g.id
inner join properties p on gp.id_property = p.id
where gp.id_good = 123;
```

выдаст вам все пары (имя_параметра, значение_параметра) для товара с id = 123.

Comment: да...думал над таким... нужно было пример!... спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

можно сознать сначала таблицу где есть на пример 4 столбца первая id автоинкремент int 5
потом price varchar 225 и так далее